# How to fscanf a file into a linkedlist?

Tags: c

so i have a file that consist of integers. And i would like to use fscanf to read the file's integers into a linkedlist. But during the compile time, the function just wait there for an input(as if there is a scanf somewhere in the function).
Please Help me :(

Code

```
struct Node{
int data;
struct Node *next;
};

typedef struct Node Node;



void fillListFromFile(Node **head)
{
    FILE *f;
    if((f=fopen("/home/fileOints001.txt","r"))==NULL)
        printf("You cannot open");
    Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    while(fscanf(f, "%d", &(newNode->data)))
    {
    newNode->next = *head;
    *head = newNode;
    Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    }

}



fillListFromFile(&head); // in the main
```

Comment: During compile time? Not running?

Comment: The complie just wait there for the user input, as if i have scanf in the function

Comment: Break it down: 1) Can you read a sequence of numbers from a file and print them out? 2) Can you construct the linked list 1->2->3? You should have gotten these two pieces working perfectly *before* you tried to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop only ends if it fails to convert the input (i.e. `fscanf()` will return 0 here). But you do not check for `EOF`. Thus, you spin your wheels trying to read over and over.  Something like:

```
int rc;

/* ... */

while ((rc = fscanf(...)) && rc != EOF) {
    /* ... */
}
```

This way you check for the end of file condition, and terminate the loop when you hit it.

Comment: or simply use `fscanf(f, "%d", &(newNode->data)) == 1`.

Comment: @hochl: Yeah, that's true! And simpler too... :)

Comment: @hochl, then it will keep reading the last integer in the file...
Isn't the fscanf will just return 0 after it reads to the end of the file? I was assuming this when i write the function.

Comment: `fscanf` will return `EOF` on ... eof :) This is defined to `-1` usually, not zero.

Comment: Right...i did while((fscanf(f, "%d", &(newNode->data)) !=EOF)
But when i print the linkedlist, it is a infinitely long lists...which mean the fscanf kept reading the last integer in the file into the list

Answer (score 0):

You need some error checking to make sure that your file parses correctly and the like.

Also, it may be a good idea not to allocate a node before its data has been successfully read.

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

Node* fillListFromFile()
{
    FILE *f;
    if(!(f = fopen("/home/fileOints001.txt","r"))) {
        perror("/home/fileOints001.txt");
        abort();
    }

    Node *head = NULL, **tail = &head, *node;
    int n;
    while(1 == fscanf(f, "%d", &n)) {
        // allocate a new node
        node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        if(!node) {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to allocate memory");
            abort();
        }

        // and append it to the list
        node->data = n;
        node->next = NULL;
        *tail = node;
        tail = &node->next;
    }
    if(!feof(f)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to parse the file");
            abort();
    }

    return head;
}
```

Comment: I would like to change the called value in my function.